# The application doesn't receive push notification after updating a new release with Firebase token. iOS / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problem with Firebase FCM token.

In the previous version of the application, users registered, but without the implemented FCM token for Push notification. And now I implemented a new version with the FCM token and after the users updated the new release they did not get the Push notification.

So I run the old version of the application without implementing the PN on my phone and then I run again, but version of the application with the implemented PN and on the console I see the FCM token in **didReceiveRegistrationToken** method, but I can not send the PN. But if I run the application for the third time, I can get PN.

For the record if I run new version of the app with implemented PN, it works perfectly.

Does anyone have any advice or solution to this problem?

Maybe some advice in global, or if I have already installed the app and re run that app again with new updates for Push Notification?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem recently with FCM.

Set `Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken` after receiving deviceToken from APNS. Although not necessary if [swizzling is enabled](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#token-swizzle-disabled), it is better to include it to ensure token is updated reliably.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I tried, but it's the same. It basically works with fcm token that I get in didReceiveRegistrationToken, and even I can send this token to the server, but until I start the application for the second time, I can not get PN with that fcm token.

It seems to me that the problem is if I run the application without the PN feature, then I run the application with a PN feature. Maybe that is a problem.

It's really weird.

Comment: O yes, I did this implementation for PN in the background.

But I do not think that's a problem, because if I run a new version of the application with PN, it works well.